# split button outlook command add-in

Tags: add-in, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I am designing a menu for an outlook add-in using Node.js

I would like that menu to behave like these [SplitButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXF6P.png) (a button that can trigger events adjacent to a dropdown menu). If you look at the splitbutton picture, It shows the paste button you see on Office Word as an exemple; if you click paste, it will paste by default but the the dropdown menu next to it has a seperate action that gives you different pasting options in the form of a dropdown menu.

I am using this the manifest found in this tutorial `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/manifests` , unfortunately the menu button cannot have any event attached to it, just give the dropdown menu.

A description of what I am trying to achieve can be found here `https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18447/SplitButton-a-NET-WinForm-control-Part-1`, the button part and the split part can have their own actions. Is there a way to do this inside the outlook add in manifest? I am using node.js
Currently the whole button works as a dropdown.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.